# How to hide login/register form when user is logged in desktop application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, desktop-application

Hello so i am working on a Java desktop application.I have already implemented the sign in and sign up part and i would like to ask how i am going to hide sign in/sign up form when the user is logged in ? i have searched on ways to do this but the answers where only php related.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should tell us which Java Frameworks you use to develop the application,like these:swing ,JavaFX,SWT.